Pardot, using an automation rule to update a field value to "blank"
In Pardot I want to be able to run an automation rule where I can target prospects with a specific lead owner ID and then in the actions, I want to be able to update that lead owner ID to blank or null. How do I go about accomplishing that? what value do i place in the field in the action so that the system will simply clear or null it out?
I tried researching the documentation but theres nothing conclusive or direct that says how to do it
